# Why gitignore is not workiing on Nextjs project?

Tags: git, next.js

I run `yarn dev` or `npm run dev` for my porject

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

My git will generate a lots of Uncommitted changes like `.next/build-manifest.json`

[image]

I check .gitignore file includes

```
# next.js
/.next/
/out/
```

Why I still get the issue ?

Comment: You cannot ignore changes to already-tracked files; only untracked files can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you added `/.next/` to `.gitignore` afterwards, so stuff that already got in GIT won't be ignored by default, only new files added to those directories.

You also need to do
`git rm --cached -r .next/` which will recursively remove the files in that directory from the cache. They should appear as untracked afterwards, and you must commit the changes

Comment: Yes, the reason is correct and the solution is working. Thanks for your help.