# Nextjs app showing changes to webpack in Git changes

Tags: git, next.js

I recently started a new Nextjs project, initialized an empty repo and starting adding changes but for some reason I'm getting hundreds of files similar to:

```
3.pack.gz
```

and

```
3bd9ca49e41297e0.webpack.hot-update.json
```

all coming from the

```
.next/static/webpack dir
```

being shown in my changes in my Source Control VSCode tab which hasn't happened to me before.

Did I mess up somewhere? Is this normal for Nextjs?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you havent commited changes in the .next dir before adding .next to gitignore? An easy way is deleting the .next dir, commiting it and then regenerating it (making sure its in gitignore) to see if changes show up

Comment: Hmm I see, I didn't add the .next dir to my .gitignore

Comment: Perhaps this question should be closed as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create-next-app adds `/.next/` to .gitignore, per https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/create-next-app/templates/app/js/gitignore#L13

If `/.next/` is not in your .gitignore you can add it yourself to ignore all these files.

Note that if you have already added the files to the repo you will need to stage the files for removal: [Why gitignore is not workiing on Nextjs project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76998658/1549818).